# backbone router and collection issue

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection and I need to access a model in the collection when a route is fired:

```
App.Houses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.House,
    url: API_URL,
})

App.houseCollection = new App.Houses()
App.houseCollection.fetch();


App.HouseDetailRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'main',
        'details/:id': 'details',
    },
    initialize: function() {

    },
    main: function() {
        App.Events.trigger('show_main_view');  
    },
    details: function(id) {
        model = App.houseCollection.get(id);
        console.log(model);
        App.Events.trigger('show_house', model);
    },
});
```

The result of that `console.log(model)` is `undefined`. I think that this is the case because the collection has not finished the `fetch()` call?

I want to attach the model to the event that I am firing so that the views that respond to the event can utilize it. I might be taking a bad approach, I am not sure.

One of the views that responds to the event:

```
App.HouseDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.house-details-area', 
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#house-details-template').html());
        App.Events.on('show_house', this.render, this);
        App.Events.on('show_main_view', this.hide, this);
    },
    events: {
        'click .btn-close': 'hide',
    },
    render: function(model) {
          var html = this.template({model:model.toJSON()});
          $(this.el).html(html);
          $(this.el).show();
    },
    hide: function() {
        $(this.el).hide();
        App.detailsRouter.navigate('/', true);
    }   
});
```

---

EDIT: Somewhat hacky fix: See details()

```
App.HouseDetailRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'main',
        'details/:id': 'details',
    },
    initialize: function() {

    },
    main: function() {
        App.Events.trigger('show_main_view');  
    },
    details: function(id) {
        if (App.houseCollection.models.length === 0) {
           // if we are browsing to website.com/#details/:id
           // directly, and the collection has not finished fetch(),
           // we fetch the model.
           model = new App.House();
           model.id = id;
           model.fetch({
               success: function(data) {
                   App.Events.trigger('show_house', data);
               } 
           });
        } else {
            // if we are getting to website.com/#details after browsing 
            // to website.com, the collection is already populated.
            model = App.houseCollection.get(id);            
            App.Events.trigger('show_house', model);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the collection has a model with that `id`? You can `console.log(App.houseCollection.models)` to see.

Comment: when calling `console.log(App.houseCollection.models` I got `[]`

Comment: Have you tried fetching the collection as needed?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. The collection is fetched at the start of the App.

Comment: I mean fetch it when you need it. Or fetch it and use it to build the links that the router would route; you could listen for a `'reset'` event and use that to trigger the stuff that renders the `details/:id` links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using neither the callbacks nor events to know when the collection's `fetch` call completes, perhaps fetching the collection is generating an error, or the model you want is not included in the server response, or you are routing to the view before `fetch` has completed.

As to your approach, here are some miscellaneous tips:

- better to pass the model to the view in the view's constructor's `options` parameter. `render()` takes no arguments and I think it is unconventional to change that.
- Always return `this` from `render()` in your views
- You can move your `this.template = _.template` code to the object literal you pass to `extend`. This code only needs to be run once per app load, not for each individual view
- For now the simplest thing may be to instantiate just a model and a view inside your `details` route function, call `fetch` on the specific model of interest, and use the `success` callback to know when to render the view.

Comment: I added my changes but they seem pretty hacky... I think I might have to rethink my structure

Comment: this got me thinking... should the collection be instantiated inside the main() route? I am not too sure about the router's functions

Comment: Use `collection.get` to check for the model. That's better than checking the length because it's more accurate about what you care about. Is the model there or not. If that doesn't return the model, then fetch the model and add it to the collection so it's there next time.